# Move files to subfolders if they match in Powershell etc?

Tags: powershell, file, move, subdirectory

I've googled for a while now but I'm unable to find any solution for this.

So I have a bunch of files in a folder, and in this folder I have subfolders.

I want to move those files to the subfolders if they match any of these.

Like this:

- some random text yellow bananas more text.txt -> \yellow bananas
- some other text red apples this is text.txt -> \red apples

Example - files:

- Propulsion_mål_2020.jpg
- Axevalla Vivid Wise As Goop.jpg
- Dagens stjärna Cyber Lane.jpg
- 640px Elian Web heat.jpg
- ...

Example - directories:

- Propulsion
- Vivid Wise As
- Cyber Lane
- Vitruvio
- ...

Target:

- 1st file goes to 1st directory
- 2nd file goes to 2nd directory
- 3rd file goes to 3rd directory
- 4th file match no directory and goes nowhere

Is it doable?

Btw, it's possible that more than one subfolder matches the filename. If so, it doesn't matter which subfolder the file is moved to.

Comment: [1] you need to define how to decide what text to match. [*grin*] [2] where is your code? what did not work as expected?

Comment: I have no code as I have no experience at all in this kind of scripting, that's the problem :)

Comment: OK ... so how do you define what part of the file name to match to your dir names?

Comment: The idea is that it should check the full file name., so some kind of regex I guess.

Comment: um, er, you STILL have not defined how to make that decision. what should one look for? where is that info stored? does one grab all the directories and then try to match that to the file name? **_please, define the steps in detail that are needed to make the decision._**

Comment: Ah, sorry. Yes, the info is stored in the subfolders names; if the filename match the name of any of the subfolders, the file will be moved there.
I appreciate your patience (guess I have no excperience explaining things neither)

Comment: ah! that makes a bit more sense - thanks! [*grin*] i used to do QualityAssurance and RequirementsCompliance for a company, so i tend to expect details. [*grin*] ///// to make things painfully clear, would you please post 2 or 3 real file name examples, 4 or 5 real directory name examples, and where the file would be moved to?

Comment: Sure! No line breaks here though which is a real bummer :/

Files:
Propulsion_mål_2020.jpg
Axevalla Vivid Wise As Goop.jpg
Dagens stjärna Cyber Lane.jpg
640px Elian Web heat.jpg
...

Directories:
Propulsion
Vivid Wise As
Cyber Lane
Vitruvio
...

1st file goes to 1st directory
2nd file goes to 2nd directory
3rd file goes to 3rd directory
4th file match no directory and goes nowhere

Comment: please, put ALL the added info into your Question so others can find it ... and wrap it in code formatting markers to make it easy to read. [*grin*]

Comment: Absolutely, thanks fo guiding me!

Comment: neato! [*grin*] that is a good enuf requirements list to build on. i just realized i missed lunch, so it will be a while before i post any code. hopefully, this Question won't be closed before then. ///// as for why it may be closed, take a look at the Tour for this site ... [*grin*] >>> Tour - Stack Overflow — https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's one way to do the job ... [*grin*] there is nearly zero error checking or handling, so you may need to add that. nor is there any record of what was done/not-done.

what it does ...

- sets the constants
  all one of them. [*grin*]
- creates the files & dirs to work with
  when you are ready to work with your own data, remove the entire `#region/#endregion` block.
- gets a list of the dirs in the target location
- creates a regex OR of the names of those dirs
- gets a list of files in the target dir
- iterates thru those files
- tests for a match of the `.BaseName` property of each file against the dir name regex from earlier
- if YES, creates a full dir name & moves the file
- if NO, writes a warning to the warning stream
  that is on by default, so you otta see it when such a file is found.
- finishes iterating thru the file list

the code ...

```
$SourceDir = "$env:TEMP\user3764769"

#region >>> create some files & dirs to work with
#    when ready to do this for real, remove this entire block
if (-not (Test-Path -LiteralPath $SourceDir))
    {
    # the $Null suppresses unwanted "what was done" output
    $Null = New-Item -Path $SourceDir -ItemType 'Directory' -ErrorAction 'SilentlyContinue'
    }
@'
Propulsion_mal_2020.jpg
Axevalla Vivid Wise As Goop.jpg
Dagens stjarna Cyber Lane.jpg
640px Elian Web heat.jpg
'@ -split [System.Environment]::NewLine |
    ForEach-Object {
        $Null = New-Item -Path $SourceDir -Name $_ -ItemType 'File' -ErrorAction 'SilentlyContinue'
        }
@'
Propulsion
Vivid Wise As
Cyber Lane
Vitruvio
'@ -split [System.Environment]::NewLine |
    ForEach-Object {
        $Null = New-Item -Path $SourceDir -Name $_ -ItemType 'Directory' -ErrorAction 'SilentlyContinue'
        }
#endregion >>> create some files & dirs to work with

$DirList = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $SourceDir -Directory
# the "|" is what regex uses for `-or`
$RegexDL = $DirList.Name -join '|'

$FileList = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $SourceDir -File

foreach ($FL_Item in $FileList)
    {
    # the matched value is stored in $Matches[0]
    if ($FL_Item.BaseName -match $RegexDL)
        {
        $DirName = $Matches[0]
        $FullDirName = Join-Path -Path $SourceDir -ChildPath $DirName

        Move-Item -LiteralPath $FL_Item.FullName -Destination $FullDirName
        }
        else
        {
        Write-Warning ''
        Write-Warning (    'No matching directory was found for [ {0} ].' -f $FL_Item.Name)
        Write-Warning '    The file was not moved.'
        }
    } # end >>> foreach ($FL_Item in $FileList)
```

output with one file that does not match any dir in the list ...

```
WARNING: 
WARNING: No matching directory was found for [ 640px Elian Web heat.jpg ].
WARNING:     The file was not moved.
```

Comment: Awesome! Works like a charm. Thank you so much for your help and once again for your patience :)

Comment: @user3764769 - you are welcome! glad to have helped ... [*grin*]